# How to bypass a actual function call for unit testing play framework and mockito library?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, playframework-2.4

I am writing unit tests for model class and its using MongoDB with playframe work. I want to skip the actual call to datastore and test the rest of the functionality.

```
//Transfer Object Class.
Class public MyModel {
    //Attributes for model.
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;

}

//Access Object Class.
Class public MyModelAccess {
    // getDs is a mongo library function which returns datastore instance.
    private DatastoreImpl datastore = getDs();
    public static boolean insert(MyModel data) {
        try {
            datastore.save(data);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
              printException(e.ErrorMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}


//Testing class.
public class TestMyModelAccess {
    MongoClient mongoTest = mock(MongoClient.class);
    Morphia morphiaTest = new Morphia();

    DatastoreImpl datastore = spy(new DatastoreImpl(morphiaTest, mongoClientTest, "TestDB"));
    doReturn(null).when(datastore).save(any(MyModelAccess.class));

    MyModelAccess obj = new MyModelAccess();
    // Add some dummy data to object.
    boolean response = MyModelAccess.insert(obj);

    assertEquals(response, true);
    verify(datastore).save(isA(MyModel.class));
}
```

I write this way by reffering [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)) but its creating an entry in the actual mongo and verify test is getting failed saying that DatastoreImpl.save(isA(MyModel)) not invoked.Although i am getting response as true.

I just want to skip the actual call to datastore.save and just want to check that it was called with the given type of argument.

Comment: `getDs();` is the actual method you need to mock if you want to bypass that behaviour. You will then specify the desired behaviour for your mocked `DatastoreImpl` and verify the interactions with it. If that's not possible for some reason, then you can use [powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) to mock the instantiation of `DatastoreImpl `

Comment: You haven't posted critically important code. And the code that you have posted doesn't compile. How does the DataStoreImpl get passed to the MyModelAccess?You're using an instance field called `datastore` from a `static` method called `insert` - that can't work. And `datastore` is retrieved using a call to `getDs()` but how does `getDs()` get the DataStoreImpl that you created in `TestModelAccess` ? (which is a class with code that's not inside a method)

Answer (score 0):

As asked by others, you need to put details of getDs() method in this question. I am assuming that you are not interested in using PowerMock or so but only Mockito. In your test class, you need to create a sub class of class under test and override this method to return a mocked `DatastoreImpl`. For method to be available for overriding, it needs to have at least package level accessibility. Then you , test this super class instead of your actual class. Code sample below ( assuming getDs() can be overridden in subclass ) - I am only pasting delta code , rest remains as is,

```
class MyModelAccessTestable extends MyModelAccess {

private DatastoreImpl datastore;

void setDataStore(DatastoreImpl datastore){
this.datastore=datastore;
}

@Override
DatastoreImpl getDs(){
 return datastore;
}
}

public class TestMyModelAccess{

@InjectMocks MyModelAccessTestable testService;

@Mock private DatastoreImpl datastore;

@Before
public void setUp(){
testService.setDataStore(datastore);
}

@Test
public void test(){
  MyModel  obj=new MyModel();
testService.insert(obj);
}

}
```

I also assume that your code has a typo , `MyModelAccess obj = new MyModelAccess();` I guess , it is - `MyModel  obj=new MyModel();`